# Kubuntu 15.10 does not recognize my graphics card

Tags: graphics, kubuntu, 15.10, amd-graphics

Today I switched my Toshiba Satellite C55D-A from Windows 8.1 to Kubuntu 15.10. When it finished installing, everything seemed fine until I noticed that my desktop effects were acting very glichty.

Knowing that this was graphics issues, I checked the KDE Info Center to see if my graphics was recognized. But unfortunately, it was identifying my AMD Radeon™ HD 8210 Graphics card as "Gallium 0.4 on AMD KABINI (DRM 2.43.0, LLVM 3.6.2)".

It looks like that Kubuntu cannot find the driver for the graphics card, but I have no idea how to install the driver on Linux. Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hit Alt+F2 to fire Krunner and then type Additional Drivers.
Open the tool and it should show the drivers available for your GPU. Go ahead and activate it.
You will need to reboot your system in order for the driver to work.

Comment: Thank you so much! The desktop effects are now practically bug-free!

Comment: Happy to help :)